# How can I delete a view from a Papyrus model?

Tags: papyrus

In Papyrus, when I create a new model, I can go to the "Welcome" tab, to the bottom-right corner, and click "Create View" to create a new view (e.g. Use Case, Sequence Diagram, etc.).

But, I did not find any way to remove a view that I created. How can I remove a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove it from the welcom page, you should go in the "Model Explorer" view and simply press Suppr.